# Strange characters after inserting string from utf8_decode into a mysql table with PHP 5.3/Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, doctrine-1.2, latin1

I'm consuming a xml (i get it by a rest service). At one point i decode a CDATA field as:

```
$version_doc = $this->getSimpleXml($uri);

if($version_doc != false){
        $equipment = utf8_decode((string)$version_doc->equipment);
}
```

This is an example of the xml field "equipment":

```
![CDATA[ABARTH: ABS, llantas de aleación de 16'', eléctrico,llantas de aleación de 17&quot; color antracita.]]
```

After i have seted the $equipment variable, if i save it in mysql (a latin1_spanish_ci collate, latin1 charset table and with Doctrine 1.2) the result in the mysql col for the row is:

ABS, llantas de aleación de 16'', eléctrico,llantas de aleación de 17?? color antracita.

Why i'm getting all the time the ?? symbol?

I'm in PHP5.3 , MySql 5 and running the server in a MAMP environment (MAC)

Comment: Well... UTF-8 can encode 100,000 characters. ISO-8859-1 a few hundreds.

Comment: so, a solution could be to change the \uwhatever code to a latin1 character before the decode?

Comment: You didn't understand me. Imagine your XML contains the `€` symbol. It cannot be encoded as [Latin 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout). You have to drop it, there's no other solution, unless you're willing to switch your database and application to UTF-8 (which is indeed the best long-term solution).

Comment: I know, what i meant is that i could change a € for a e or something similar, not equal. I'm trying this and getting good results for now. I also thought about to change everything to UTF8, it would be nicier...

Comment: Alvaro, so you were right, that was the problem... i made the str_replace's before the utf8_encode and now it works fine! stack overflow should add a feature to pay a beer to people like you. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario [MySQL Latin1 means Windows-1252](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html), just like ISO-8859-1 means Windows-1252 in browsers

Comment: @Esailija - Funny. I knew they were commonly confused but I had never thought it could slip into MySQL internals (though such kind of errors are to expect when we talk about MySQL, where even UTF-8 is not actually UTF-8).